# Executor Singleton not started after upgrading android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

after i upgrade android studio and i opened it, i get this error :

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugTestSources] :app:preBuild :app:preDebugBuild
>   :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAstuetzPagerslidingtabstrip101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers120Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta112Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics224Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGithubHotchemiAndroidRate043Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices730Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds730Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable730Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric131Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>
> > Executor Singleton not started

Note: i override the old version of android studio under C:\programs\android by the downloded one and i kept the old configuration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem. For me the issue was that I was using Android plugin version 1.0.0 which was not compatible with Gradle version 2.4 (which happened after the upgrade). The issue was solved after I upgraded my Android plugin version to 1.2.0

Comment: I stumbled upon this issue after updating to Android studio 1.3. Changed the gradle build version in build.gradle file from 1.0.0 to 1.2.3 version. That resolved the issue

Comment: how to upgrade the plugin?

Comment: You can edit the build.gradle in your project a to change the version. Then syncing the project using the "Sync project with gradle" option on top bar(Next to AVD Manager button) should upgrade the gradle version.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading the gradle version in build.gradel from 1.0.0 to 1.2.3 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has something to do with Gradle being launched in daemon mode. I get this error every once in a while also in the command line.

In case you encounter a `Executor Singleton not started` issue, you can workaround it by stopping the Gradle daemon: `./gradlew --stop`. Then you can rebuild.